# How to solve this error while installing Next.js with yarn - options.env['npm_config__p_a_c_k_a_g_e___l_o_c_k_']' must be a string without null bytes

Tags: next.js, hadoop-yarn

While creating a Next.js app with yarn using `"yarn create next-app"`, it throws this error - `An unexpected error occurred: "The property 'options.env['npm_config__p_a_c_k_a_g_e___l_o_c_k_']' must be a string without null bytes. Received '\x00t\x00r\x00u\x00e\x00'"`

Node version - 19.4.0

NPM version - 9.7.2

Yarn version - 1.22.19

`create-next-app codeswear` This command works fine, but I can't install the older versions of Next.js with this command.

`yarn create next-app@latest` and `yarn create next-app@12` - I also tried these commands but did not work.

I tried many things but nothing worked at all.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue with Yarn while working with a StencilJS project.  The thing that solved it for me was deleting the `.npmrc` and `.yarnrc` files in my home directory.  If you don't want to lose the contents of those files, obviously back them up before you mess with them.

Yarn is reading the NPM and Yarn configuration files during the process of setting up a project.  If Yarn can't parse the data in those files for one reason or another, it will throw an error.

Comment: I was getting a similar error when running `yarn install` - `The property 'options.env['npm_config_______r_e_g_i_s_t_r_y___n_p_m_j_s___o_r_g_______a_u_t_h_T_o_k_e_n_']' must be a string without null bytes.`.

Removing above mentioned files solved it for me! (go to C:\Users\{YourUser}\AppData and search for those files and delete them).

Please note that only `yarn install` was failing while `npm install` worked fine